# MediaPlayer setVolume() on 4 channels

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, volume

I understand through MediaPlayer I can control 2 audio channels - the left and right side. Would it be possible to expand that and control 4 audio channels individually as well?

Here I play both my left and right at full

```
yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
```

And then I can just play my left at full

```
yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Since I have the ability to monitor each channel on my monitor, is there a way to do something like this?

```
yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 0.7f, 0.5f, 0.2f);
```

Comment: ... **[no](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setVolume(float,%20float))**. By the way, it would make little or no sense on a typical phone or tablet - which is normally a **stereo** device, not a **quadrophonic** one.

Comment: As @KlingKlang correctly pointed, via MediaPlayer you won't go too far. But there are news coming via USB, see this: https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb and this as an example https://www.extreamsd.com/index.php/technology/usb-audio-driver . There is an interesting discussion here too: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160385/how-to-play-5-1-audio-direct-to-speakers